# Why isn't Backpack using CSS?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

Installed Backpack on a fresh Laravel install. Maybe I'm missing something but is it normal for the views Backpack adds to have no CSS? It's pure HTML with no formatting. I've watched videos of people installing it and they show the webpage properly formatted.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, if properly inatalled Backpack does come with CSS and JS. To get it, you should follow the [installation steps in the documentation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/installation).

One important step that you might have missed is “php artisan backpack:install”, which will also publish the needed CSS and JS.